# How to add multiple custom fields to a wp_query in a shortcode?

Tags: shortcode, wordpress

In a shortcode I can limit `wp_query` results by custom field values.

Example:

```
[my-shortcode meta_key=my-custom-field meta_value=100,200 meta_compare='IN']
```

And obviously it's possible to use multiple custom fields in a `wp_query` like [WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)

But how can I use multiple custom fields in my shortcode? At the moment I do pass all the shortcode parameters with `$atts`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On of a few different solutions might be to use a JSON encoded format for the meta values.  Note that this isn't exactly user-friendly, but certainly would accomplish what you want.

You would of course need to generate the json encoded values first and ensure they are in the proper format.  One way of doing that is just using PHP's built in functions:

```
// Set up your array of values, then json_encode them with PHP
$values = array(
    array('key' => 'my_key',
        'value' => 'my_value',
        'operator'  => 'IN'
    ),
    array('key' => 'other_key',
        'value' => 'other_value',
    )
);

echo json_encode($values);
// outputs: [{"key":"my_key","value":"my_value","operator":"IN"},{"key":"other_key","value":"other_value"}]
```

Example usage in the shortcode:

```
[my-shortcode meta='[{"key":"my_key","value":"my_value","operator":"IN"},{"key":"other_key","value":"other_value"}]']
```

Which then you would parse out in your shortcode function, something like so:

```
function my_shortcode($atts ) {
    $meta = $atts['meta'];
    // decode it "quietly" so no errors thrown
    $meta = @json_decode( $meta );
    // check if $meta set in case it wasn't set or json encoded proper
    if ( $meta && is_array( $meta ) ) {
        foreach($meta AS $m) {
            $key = $m->key;
            $value = $m->value;
            $op = ( ! empty($m->operator) ) ? $m->operator : '';

            // put key, value, op into your meta query here....
        }
    }
}
```

**Alternate Method**
Another method would be to cause your shortcode to accept an arbitrary number of them, with matching numerical indexes, like so:

```
[my-shortcode meta-key1="my_key" meta-value1="my_value" meta-op1="IN
    meta-key2="other_key" meta-value2="other_value"]
```

Then, in your shortcode function, "watch" for these values and glue them up yourself:

```
function my_shortcode( $atts ) {
    foreach( $atts AS $name => $value ) {
        if ( stripos($name, 'meta-key') === 0 ) {
            $id = str_ireplace('meta-key', '', $name);
            $key = $value;
            $value = (isset($atts['meta-value' . $id])) ? $atts['meta-value' . $id] : '';
            $op = (isset($atts['meta-op' . $id])) ? $atts['meta-op' . $id] : '';

            // use $key, $value, and $op as needed in your meta query

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What could cause a meta query not to work?

This works very well, but in the specific website where I need it, WP_Query simply ignores the meta_query array. So the query returns my posts, even all other filter arguments work, but not the meta_query.

And no, it's definitely no typing error or something like that. I've tried everything for many many hours now, copied the relevant code parts from different sources, tried different custom fields... but everything without success.
Can there be any other code in my theme or in a plugin that stops the meta query from working?

Comment: I'd be happy to help, but that needs to be a new question.  Start a new question, be sure it includes the relevant information about **how** your meta query is structured, and then people can help.  (You can "ping" me by adding the question, then making a comment with @cale_b in it, and I'll know you posted the question)